# Pass list of categories to partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a partial view which will display list of Main Categories and under each Main Category all of its subcategories. But the problem is I don't know how can I pass this Category List to my partial view. Please check the code bellow. I've also attached my .edmx table map picture to give you better idea. Once I pass it to partial view I want to loop though all categories and sub categories to display them

[image: pic]

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public PartialViewResult _GuestNav()
{
    using (var db = new TestEntities())
    {
        db.Categories.ToList(); // get list from here

        return PartialView("_GuestNav"); // then pass that list to partial view
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the main action code:

```
public ActionResult Categories()
{
    using (var dbCtx = new DbContext())
    {
        var categories = dbCtx.Categories.Include(x => x.SubCategories).ToList()
        return View(categories); 
    }
}
```

Then in your `Categories.cshtml` you will have the code as below:

```
@model IEnumerable<Categories>

<ul>
    @foreach(var category in Model)
    {
        <li>@category.CategoryName
         @if(category.SubCategories.Any())
         {
            Html.RenderPartial("~/Partial/_SubCategory.cshtml", category.SubCategories); 
         }
         </li>
    }
</ul>
```

At last you supply a partial view called `_SubCategory.cshtml` in the Partial folder of Category folder as below:

```
 @model IEnumerable<SubCategory>
 <ul>
    @foreach(var subCategory in Model)
    {
        <li>@subCategory.SubCategoryName</li>
    }
</ul>
```

In your case if you want to pass this list to the partial view you specified you can do it as below:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public PartialViewResult _GuestNav()
{
    using (var db = new TestEntities())
    {
       var categories = db.Categories.Include(x => x.SubCategories).ToList(); // Added the include if you want to add subcategories as well
        return PartialView("_GuestNav", categories); // then pass that list to partial view
    }
}
```

Comment: Bro there is no main action. I am calling partial view from _Layout.cshtml

Comment: Well in that case use the last example and customize the partial view as you want. Keep in mind to set `@model IEnumerable<Categories>` at the top of the partial view

Answer (score 0):

The [PartialView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.partialview(v=vs.118).aspx#Anchor_8) method has an override that accepts an object. You need to store the results of the db.Categories.ToList() call in a variable and pass that to the method like this:

```
 using (var db = new TestEntities())
{
    var cats = db.Categories.Include("SubCategories").ToList(); // get list from here

    return PartialView("_GuestNav", cats); // then pass that list to partial view
}
```

Just make sure your partial view expects a list of categories as its model. Then, inside your view you can iterate over the model and display the subcategories.

You should also look into how to use a viewmodel for your views.

**EDIT**

You may need to use an include statement since navigation properties are generally lazy loaded. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yo can use model binding, pass a Model or ViewModel as a parameter and access it from the partial view. For example, in your `_GuestNav` action:

```
...
return PartialView("_GuestNav",db.Categories.ToList());
```

Here's a [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial#accessing-data-from-partial-views) on how to accomplish that.

Then you can bind the model in your view. For example:

```
...
@model IEnumerable<Categories>;
```

For more detail, check out the examples from the link.

Comment: You should include a `@using` statement indicating the full path to the  `Categories` class. For example `@using PartialViewsSample.ViewModels`.

Comment: Please note that I edited my answer changing `@model List<Categories>;` into `@model IEnumerable<Categories>;`